# Security header is not valid (python)

Tags: python, security, paypal

I am trying to use the TransactionSearch API to bring up merchant transaction history. I have been stuck with a "security header is not valid error" and wasn't able to find a solution in the other posts. My code works fine on the sandbox server and I generated live credentials+signature from PayPal. I assume that if they gave me credentials that I have permission to access the API.

My python code is as follows:

```
import requests
def getTransactionHistory(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    headers = {'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID' : api_username, 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD' : api_password,
               'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE' : api_sig}
    data = 'USER=' + api_username + '&PWD=' + api_password + '&SIGNATURE=' + api_sig + '&METHOD=' + \
           'TransactionSearch' + '&STARTDATE=' + start_datetime + '&ENDDATE=' + end_datetime + \
    '&VERSION=94'
    print data
    req = requests.post(base+nvp_point, data=data)
    return req.text

r = getTransactionHistory('2012-01-01T05:38:48Z', '2012-01-02T05:38:48Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct. There was a '-' in my signature or password, which was not copy-pasted correctly. Solved.